# How to perfectly overfit neural network to memorize input?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting

Say I have 15 data points (x values), for which I have corresponding y values (say randomly generated). For learning purposes, I am trying design a neural network which perfectly matches the input data, i.e. overfits as much as possible. I cant get this done beyond certain point.

Running millions of epochs, designing networks having from 1 to about 4 layers, each layer having from 1 to thousands of neurons..., using ReLU or sigmoid to force non-linearity - all this and it still wont overfit. Am I missing something? Is it even possible when I have only one input?

For example, this is the output of NN 1,2048,2048,2048,1 with sigmoids after 200k epochs (practically no change since 60k)

[image: graph]

This actually does not look like overfitting at all. Confused, appreciate any pointers. Maybe I need some "funny" activation function?

**Update**
Thanks for all the comment suggestions. After digging in a bit more, here are my take-aways.

- Use full batch, not mini-batch/SGD. I was however using that, if SGD in torch is fed the entire data set, it is full gradient descent.
- My loss function was MSE, i.e. optimizer was taking mean of all the errors squared, for this purpose just summing the errors works better. Mean sort-of anti overfits here.
- Some dataset might not be perfectly representable by a mathematical function, i.e. there might two identical data points with assigned different results (i.e. 3->9 and 3->7 due to randomness). Obviously this is not possible to capture by NN.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include your data, information about your architecture and learning procedure?

Comment: Just because the ANN fits the data extremely well (or even *perfectly*) does not mean the model is overfitting. That meaning said there are many types of ANN. Depending on the data and the expectations, you might choose one type over another. I would start there. Do you know what the best type of ANN to employ for your data is?

Comment: Use full batch instead of minibatch

Comment: Also, what optimizer are you using? What is the learning rate?

Comment: See here for an interactive demonstration: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/regression.html

Comment: Using the sum instead of the mean for the loss is the same as adjusting the learning rate, so your discovery is that a different learning rate finds a different solution/finds the desired solution more quickly. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358786/mean-or-sum-of-gradients-for-weight-updates-in-sgd/358971#358971